# Remove class when move to next menu item

Tags: jquery

I have a simple nav made up of the following HTML;

```
<div class="inner">
<div class="button"><img class="portal" src="images/portalbutton.png" /></div>
<a href="#"><div class="prod_description">&nbsp;</div></a>
</div>
```

There are a number of items (All set to float left along side each other) to make up a nav bar.

When I hover over `.button` and/or `.prod_description` I want the `.inner` `<div>` to have the class `.hover` added to it. This is so I can set a background image around the whole thing (Kind of like highlighting the nav item).

I only then want to remove `.hover` when another `.button or .prod_description` is hovered over, in which case this nav item takes the `.hover` class.

Comment: Why not just set the background of the .inner div when you hover over .button or .prod_description? Why do you need to add .hover to .inner?

Comment: In that case how can I remove the background only when I hover over another .inner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I hover over `.button` and/or `.prod_description` I want the `.inner` `<div>` to have the class `.hover` added to it.

Unless your CSS is positioning things in a very clever way, this would be the same as hovering the `.inner` itself, right? If so, the task can be solves as easy as:

```
$('.inner').hover(function() {
    $('.inner').removeClass('hover');
    $(this).addClass('hover');
});
```

If my assumption about the positioning doesn't hold, the code will have to look more like this:

```
$('.inner .button, .inner .prod_description').hover(function() {
    $('.inner').removeClass('hover');
    $(this).parents('.inner').addClass('hover');
});
```

In the latter code sample, notice the use of [**`parents()`**](http://api.jquery.com/parents/) - not to be confused with `parent()`.

Comment: Nice and simple, and a reduction in code. Used second option.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".button").hover(
   function () {
      $(".inner").removeClass("hover");
      $(this).parent(".inner").addClass("hover");
   },
   function () {}
 );
 $(".prod_description").hover(
   function () {
      $(".inner").removeClass("hover");
      $(this).parent("a").parent("inner").addClass("hover");
   },
   function () {}
 ); });
```

Comment: Does exactly what is required, copy & paste, Bingo!

Comment: You can remove a lot of the redundant Javascript if you change your markup a bit. See below.

Comment: Agreed, if the 'a' tag is put inside the prod_description div then you could combine all that into one .hover call instead of having two .hover bindings

Comment: @danit: I believe my answer displays a much more simple way to do the same (without changing the markup): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2517267/remove-class-when-move-to-next-menu-item/2517333#2517333

Answer (score 1):

With this small change to your html, the Javascript will be a little easier to write:

```
<div class="inner">
    <div class="button"><img class="portal" src="images/portalbutton.png" /></div>
    <div class="prod_description"><a href="#">stuff</a></div>
</div>
```

Then, your Javscript function looks like this.  When you hover an item, it removes the `hover` class from all items and applies it to the current one. That way, the `hover` class will stay, even when moving away from the item.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('div.button, div.prod_description').mouseover(function() {
                $('div.inner').removeClass('hover');
                $(this).parent().addClass('hover'); //The HTML change was to allow the call to parent() to be the same
            });
        });
```